# Use a string as an object name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
console.log(window.Ab); //returns 12345
```

I would like to rename Ab to something that has meaning to be used throughout the code of my chrome extension
I was thinking about doing something like this

```
const meaningfulObjectName = 'Ab'
console.log(window.meaningfulObjectName); // should return the value of window.Ab, 12345
```

However I seem to be making a mistake. How can I correct this?

Comment: `window[meaningfulObjectName]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to access the property.

**Here's how you can do this**:

```
const meaningfulObjectName = 'Ab';
console.log(window[meaningfulObjectName]); // This will return the value of window.Ab, 12345
```